# Prevent cmd start command to open parameters containing spaces as files

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I have an Excel macro which accepts command line parameters when passed in the following way:

```
start excel.exe c:\cmdr.xlsm -param1 -param2 -param3
```

The macro

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Debug.Assert False

Dim parameters As Variant
Dim i As Integer

parameters = CmdLineToVariant

For i = 1 To UBound(parameters)
MsgBox ("Your parameter " & i & " was " & parameters(i))
Next i

End Sub

Public Function CmdLineToVariant() As Variant

Dim Buffer() As Byte
Dim StrLen As Long
Dim CmdPtr As Long
Dim line As String
Dim lineSplitted As Variant
Dim parameters As String
Dim i As Integer

CmdPtr = GetCommandLine()
If CmdPtr > 0 Then
  StrLen = lstrlenW(CmdPtr) * 2
  If StrLen > 0 Then
    ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
    CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal CmdPtr, StrLen

    line = Buffer
    lineSplitted = Split(line, "-")

    CmdLineToVariant = lineSplitted
  End If
End If

End Function
```

It works fine when there are no spaces in the names of parameters, however I get some annoying errors when there are whitespaces like here

```
start excel.exe c:\cmdr.xlsm -param 1 -param 2 -param 3
```

After my macro successfully completes I get errors like "1.xlsx could not be found", "2.xlsx could not be found" and finally "3.xlsx could not be found".

Is there a way to prevent these errors to appear while retaining the same syntax and logic for passing parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `"quote parameters"`.

There's a quirk with `start` however, that the very first `"quoted argument"` is used as a window-title.

Use

```
start "" excel.exe c:\cmdr.xlsm "-param 1" "-param 2" "-param 3"
```

or possibly

```
start "" excel.exe c:\cmdr.xlsm -"param 1" -"param 2" -"param 3"
```

(untested - OP provides no indication as to what the parameters are).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When using quotes as you suggested in either way the parameters are not sent to the macro. I've added the macro code to the question.